# How secure would it be to use my toy bingo machine to generate a bitcoin private key?

Tags: private-key

Am I right in thinking there are 90! possibilities.
Would it be random?
Would you trust this technique?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RYbc.jpg

Comment: But only if you always fill up all 90 fields. If you also allow shorter combinations there are even more! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address space has 2<sup>160</sup> possible addresses, so to fully benefit from that space, you'd need to surpass a space of

> 2<sup>160</sup> = 1.46E48 combinations.

This is achieved by picking 26 numbers from your toy bingo machine as

> 90!/64! = 1.17E49

while you keep track of the order in which they are picked.

---

To achieve at least 64 bit of entropy, you'd need 10 numbers (order recorded) from your toy bingo machine:

> 90!/80! = 2.07E19 > 1.84E19 = 2<sup>64</sup>

Which was suggested as a minimum on the related question: [How many throws of a dice are necessary to defeat a brute force attack?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22159/5406)

All numbers are assuming that the toy bingo machine acts reasonably random.